# MVC2: JQuery not working when the Details page is paginated

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, pagination, master-detail

#### The problem:

I have an MVC2 project that uses a Details page and a Master page.  When the Details page runs the first time, everything is great - all the javascript and jquery runs just fine.  However, when the pagination runs (using a PaginatedList a la the NerdDinner tutorial), the second page doesn't load the jquery object.  (JQuery = "undefined").

I have no idea why the second page doesn't work.  I have pared down the solution to the following minimum code to show the behavior:

#### The Master.aspx page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
          "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
</title>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" 
            type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert('MasterPage');
    });
</script>

<%-- scripts from child pages get inserted here --%>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</div>
</body>
```

#### The Details.aspx Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
         MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"     
         Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WidgetViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="TitleContent" 
             ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" 
             runat="server">
The Title
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" 
             ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent" 
             runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert('DetailsPage');
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%-- No Content --%>
</asp:Content>
```

- The JQuery library is the only library I am loading.
- The scripts shown above are the only scripts I have.

#### The Source of Details/{somequery} (both alerts show as expected)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title>

The Title

</title>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" 
            type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert('MasterPage');
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert('DetailsPage');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### The Source code of Details/{somequery}/1 (ONLY the Details.aspx alert works)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

The Title

</title>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" 
            type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        alert('MasterPage');
    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert('DetailsPage');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's how you have the src of your jquery.  change it to `/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with @Josh's comment, as depending on your route that relative path is going to change... Make it absolute, or better yet use the CDN version of jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Marking this as answer, as it lead me down the right path.  I used <%: ResolveUrl() %> to resolve the URL and all is good.